# Returning a JSON Response after Select/Insert data to Database

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

NET Web API to insert and select data from the SQL Server. I'm using Postman to call the Web API. When I'm requesting the Web API with JSON body I'm expecting Postman to respond back the expected value in JSON response body. This is my JSON request in Postman. As you can see, I request a tac and temp_token.

```
{
       "tac":"300191", 
       "temp_token":"wtlSz2nWakOFPMpkH8vYEA=="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

But turns out that Postman will only response *True*.

This should be a response from Postman that I expected

```
{
    "customer _id": "LCE202101245002",
     "response": {
        "code": 00,
        "response_message": "Success"
    }
}
```

Here is the C# code that I develop using the MVC design pattern. I'm using stored procedure instead of SQL query in services class.

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/Account/Verify_tac")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult verifyTac(TacVerify_Model sso)
{
    SSOService verify_tac = new SSOService();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return Ok(verify_tac.DoTacVerify(sso));
}
```

**Services**

```
public bool DoTacVerify(TacVerify_Model objsso)
{            
        bool _return = false;

        SqlParameter[] parm =
        {
            new SqlParameter("temp_token", objsso.temp_token),
            new SqlParameter("tac", objsso.tac)
        };

    var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["_cs"].ConnectionString;
    dbUtil db = new dbUtil(connectionString);
    DataSet ds = db.Select("SSO_TAC_VERIFY", parm);
        if (ds.Tables.Count == 0) return _return;
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        if (dt == null) return _return;
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0) return _return;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            _return = true;
        }

        return _return;
}
```

**Login_Model class**

```
public class Login_Model
{
    private DataRow dataRow;

    public Login_Model(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        this.dataRow = dataRow;
    }

    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string secure_word { get; set; }
    public string provider_id { get; set; }
    public string temp_token { get; set; }
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```sql
USE [HISDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SSO_TAC_VERIFY]    Script Date: 2/4/2021 3:17:41 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SSO_TAC_VERIFY]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    --@customer_id nvarchar(255),
    @temp_token nvarchar(255),
    @tac nvarchar(6)
AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    
     -- Insert statements for procedure here
     SELECT CUSTOMER_ID from ACCOUNT_INFO WHERE 
     TEMP_TOKEN=@temp_token AND TAC=@tac

END
```

Comment: Is that the postman response you expect, or the one you're actually getting?

Comment: the one i expect @ekke

Comment: No surprise here, you are returning to the client what is returned by DoTacVerify which is boolean. So why are you expecting to return something different?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the DataSet result to JSON, then only you will get the response in JSON.

Ex:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```